# Iterate over array with nested objects

Tags: reactjs

**PROBLEM:** I need to access the `linkTitle` values for each object in my array.

Here is how my `savedLinksData` array is structured:

[image]

And here is my code:

```js
 {savedLinksData.map((saved, key) => (
        <h1>{saved.linkType}</h1>
      ))}
```

Full Code:

```js
// query for saved links data
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      async function fetchData() {
        const request = await db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user)
          .collection("saved")
          .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
            setSavedLinks(
              snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
            )
          );
      }
      fetchData();
    } else {
      setSavedLinks([]);
    }
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (savedLinks.length > 0) {
      let newArray = [];
      savedLinks.map((saved) => {
        db.collection("users")
          .doc(saved.savedUser)
          .collection("links")
          .doc(saved.savedLinkId)
          .get()
          .then(function (doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
              // console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
              newArray.push(doc.data());
              // setSavedLinksData([...savedLinksData, doc.data()]);
            } else {
              // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
              console.log("No such document!");
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
          });
      });
      setSavedLinksData(newArray);
    }
  }, [savedLinks]);

  console.log("RETURNED LINKS DATA", savedLinksData);
  console.log("SAVED", savedLinks);
```

Comment: The items in your array don' seem to have a linkTitle property. is it a property nested in one of the subDocuments?

Comment: So just change ```saved.linkType``` to ```saved.linkTitle```. I can't really tell the shape of your data though, it would better if you could provide the code, not just an image :)

Comment: @MathieuK. Sorry, the ```linkTitle``` is nested in my ```linkInfo``` object

Comment: @KyleLambert Hey man! Sorry about that! The ```linkTitle``` is nested in the ```linkInfo``` object

Comment: All good, if its nested inside ```linkInfo``` then you can access it via dot notation ```saved.linkInfo.linkTitle```. Does this work for you

Comment: @KyleLambert Yes, I've been trying that. However, I see the data flash on my screen quickly and then it disappears. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Its hard to tell from the code you've provided, can you include the full code for the component?

Comment: @KyleLambert Just updated! Also, I'm a newbie at react/coding so do let me know how I can improve the code or if you see anything generally wrong. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: you need to use return inside your map method inorder to display the HTML elemet

Comment: `{savedLinksData.map((saved, key) => (
        return <h1>{saved.linkInfo.linkTitle}</h1>
      ))}`

Comment: @sharunkk I think there may be something wrong with your syntax

Comment: @RogerStaxx if you are returning single elemt you don't need brackets in return statement.is that you mean ?

Comment: @sharunkk I'm looping through an array and your return statement doesn't work

Comment: Posted an answer. Plz upvote comments and answer , and accept (if it solves your question) I am trying to get points 

Answer (score 0):

You can do  `{savedLinksData.map((saved, key) => ( <h1>{saved.linkInfo.linkTitle}</h1> ))}`